# Flutter: App Crashes with Runtime Exception - Reply already submitted

Tags: exception, flutter, dart, permissions, android-permissions

I'm using [sms_maintained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained) in my application, and when sending message method is called, it prompts for the permission and as soon as we allow; the app crashes with this error in console.

```
D/AndroidRuntime(16973): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(16973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16973): Process: com.alena.my_application, PID: 16973
E/AndroidRuntime(16973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.alena.my_application/com.alena.my_application.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4617)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4659)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at com.babariviere.sms.SmsSenderMethodHandler.sendSmsMessage(SmsSender.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at com.babariviere.sms.SmsSenderMethodHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(SmsSender.java:71)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterPluginRegistry.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivityDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityDelegate.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivity.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7941)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7763)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4610)
E/AndroidRuntime(16973):    ... 11 more
I/Process (16973): Sending signal. PID: 16973 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

I found, many other developers are having same issue for `sms` and `camera` permissions.

**Q.** Is there any fix available?

Comment: please help, the app is ready and this is the only bug and it is delaying delivery. :(

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. @alena did you found any solution for this?

Comment: sorry for late reply, I did not find any solution but I did it using another package [flutter_sms](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms). The procedure was different, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Alena but flutter_sms cannot send sms automatically, yes?

Comment: @SardorbekRkh you are right, the app can't send message itself. Our app can just launch sms app with prewritten sms and user have to press **Send** button to send text message.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [sms_maintained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained) in contrast to its name, seems to be no longer being updated. As for the error that you're getting, it seems to be an Android permission issue caused by the plugin that you're using. Since the plugin is no longer maintained, you may want to consider migrating to a more up-to-date sms plugin like [flutter_sms](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms).

Comment: This isn't a permission issue. The root cause is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted`. The plugin in question must be trying to invoke `result.success(..)` multiple times. A plugin can only return a single result per method channel call.